# Call filter (subset) twice in a function in R

Tags: r, function, filter, dplyr, subset

I'd like to write a function that uses the `dplyr::filter()` function to subset my data into 10 year time slices. My function is as below, but this appears to only return the value from the second call to `filter()`.

How can a write a function that will subset the data into multiple time periods, then summarise the data?

## Example data

```
aggr.data <- dput(head(aggr.data))
structure(list(time = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), 
dayofyr = 1:6, NPP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
soc = c(2582.0408, 2582.3461, 2582.7023, 2582.9979, 2583.1896, 2583.4067)),
.Names = c("time", "dayofyr", "NPP", "soc"), 
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here, I'm attempting to filter the time periods of 2020 - 2029 and then 2030 to 2039. Then I'd like to be able to aggregate data by these 'subsets'.

## Function

```
 testFunction <- function(x) {
      time2020 <- filter(x, time >= 2020, time <= 2029.92);
      time2040 <- filter(x, time>= 2030, time <= 2039.92);
      test1 <- summarise(time2020, mean.soc = mean(soc), mean.npp = sum(NPP/20));
      test2 <- summarise(time2040, mean.soc = mean(soc), mean.npp = sum(NPP/20))
    }
```

Run the function on the data

```
testFunction(aggr.data)
```

Comment: Is the issue with what the function is returning? Did you try `list('test1' = test1, 'test2' = test2)` in the last line of the function? Also, you may want to specify `dplyr::filter()`.

Comment: ahh yes! I did not know about list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody has answered, I'll answer based on bouncyball's comment. 
The function needs the `list()` argument.

```
   testFunction <- function(x) {
          time2020 <- filter(x, time >= 2020, time <= 2029.92);
          time2040 <- filter(x, time>= 2030, time <= 2039.92);
          test1 <- summarise(time2020, mean.soc = mean(soc), mean.npp = sum(NPP/20));
          test2 <- summarise(time2040, mean.soc = mean(soc), mean.npp = sum(NPP/20))   
 list('test1' = test1, 'test2' = test2)
        }
```